# Why doesn't Type.GetFields() return backing fields in a base class?

Tags: c#, reflection, properties, backing-field

In C#, if you use `Type.GetFields()` with a type representing a derived class, it will return a) all explicitly declared fields in the derived class, b) all backing fields of automatic properties in the derived class and c) all explicitly declared fields in the base class.

Why are the d) backing fields of automatic properties in the base class missing?

Example:

```
public class Base {
    public int Foo { get; set; }
}
public class Derived : Base {
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        FieldInfo[] fieldInfos = typeof(Derived).GetFields(
            BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic |
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy
        );
        foreach(FieldInfo fieldInfo in fieldInfos) {
            Console.WriteLine(fieldInfo.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

This will show only the backing field of Bar, not Foo.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A field being a backing field has no influence on reflection. The only relevant property of backing fields is that they are private.

Reflection functions don't return *private* members of base classes, even if you use `FlattenHierarchy`. You will need to loop manually over your class hierarchy and ask for private fields on each one.

I think `FlattenHierarchy` is written with the intent to show all members visible to code in the class you look at. So base members can be hidden/shadowed by members with the same name in a more derived class and private members are not visible at all.

Comment: FlattenHierarchy Has the following Comment                                                  Specifies that public and protected static members up the hierarchy should be
returned. Private static members in inherited classes are not returned. Static
members include fields, methods, events, and properties. Nested types are not returned.                                                                                                         It mentions the word static here, which is makes me think it wont work for none static members

Answer (score 8):

Here is a revised version using HashSet:

```
public static FieldInfo[] GetFieldInfosIncludingBaseClasses(Type type, BindingFlags bindingFlags)
{
    FieldInfo[] fieldInfos = type.GetFields(bindingFlags);

    // If this class doesn't have a base, don't waste any time
    if (type.BaseType == typeof(object))
    {
        return fieldInfos;
    }
    else
    {   // Otherwise, collect all types up to the furthest base class
        var currentType = type;
        var fieldComparer = new FieldInfoComparer();
        var fieldInfoList = new HashSet<FieldInfo>(fieldInfos, fieldComparer);
        while (currentType != typeof(object))
        {
            fieldInfos = currentType.GetFields(bindingFlags);
            fieldInfoList.UnionWith(fieldInfos);
            currentType = currentType.BaseType;
        }
        return fieldInfoList.ToArray();
    }
}

private class FieldInfoComparer : IEqualityComparer<FieldInfo>
{
    public bool Equals(FieldInfo x, FieldInfo y)
    {
        return x.DeclaringType == y.DeclaringType && x.Name == y.Name;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(FieldInfo obj)
    {
        return obj.Name.GetHashCode() ^ obj.DeclaringType.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: "Cygon's sample function only retrieves fields of base classes if the class has base classes != object." - I don't get what you're trying to say. I initialized my `List<FieldInfo>` with the fields from the starting type, just like you do the `HashSet<FieldInfo>`, so both solutions will contain the starting type's fields as well.

Comment: Otherwise, nicely done, especially that you use `UnionWith()`, much more elegant than my array scan. Performance wise, the `HashSet` doesn't seem to do much, I tried it with 30 fields in 3 levels of inheritance for 1,000,000 iterations, finishing in 7157 ms (List) vs 7160 ms (HashSet).

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, you are right. It might have been an intermediate implementation which had that limitation and I assumed it was yours. I removed my statement in the above text.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks go to @CodeInChaos for the quick and complete answer!

In case anyone else stumbles across this, here's a quick workaround that follows the fields up to the furthest base class.

```
/// <summary>
///   Returns all the fields of a type, working around the fact that reflection
///   does not return private fields in any other part of the hierarchy than
///   the exact class GetFields() is called on.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="type">Type whose fields will be returned</param>
/// <param name="bindingFlags">Binding flags to use when querying the fields</param>
/// <returns>All of the type's fields, including its base types</returns>
public static FieldInfo[] GetFieldInfosIncludingBaseClasses(
    Type type, BindingFlags bindingFlags
) {
    FieldInfo[] fieldInfos = type.GetFields(bindingFlags);

    // If this class doesn't have a base, don't waste any time
    if(type.BaseType == typeof(object)) {
        return fieldInfos;
    } else { // Otherwise, collect all types up to the furthest base class
        var fieldInfoList = new List<FieldInfo>(fieldInfos);
        while(type.BaseType != typeof(object)) {
            type = type.BaseType;
            fieldInfos = type.GetFields(bindingFlags);

            // Look for fields we do not have listed yet and merge them into the main list
            for(int index = 0; index < fieldInfos.Length; ++index) {
                bool found = false;

                for(int searchIndex = 0; searchIndex < fieldInfoList.Count; ++searchIndex) {
                    bool match =
                        (fieldInfoList[searchIndex].DeclaringType == fieldInfos[index].DeclaringType) &&
                        (fieldInfoList[searchIndex].Name == fieldInfos[index].Name);

                    if(match) {
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if(!found) {
                    fieldInfoList.Add(fieldInfos[index]);
                }
            }
        }

        return fieldInfoList.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Be aware that I'm manually comparing the fields in a nested for loop. If you have deeply nested classes or monstrously big classes, feel free to use a HashSet<> instead.

EDIT: Also be aware that this doesn't search types further down in the inheritance chain. In my case I know that I'm at the most derived type when callling the method.