# Backing fields for hidden properties

Tags: c#, reflection, properties

Let's say I have the following example classes:

```
public class Base
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public new string Value { get; set; }

    public bool IsBaseValueSet()
    {
        return base.Value != 0;
    }

    public void SetBaseValue(int value)
    {
        base.Value = value;
    }
}
```

The property `Value` is hidden in `Derived` and replaced with a property of type `string`. Now if do:

```
var properties = typeof(Derived).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

I am going to get only one property, which is the `Value` in the class `Derived`. Furthermore, if I examine the class fields:

```
var fields = typeof(Derived).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

I am still going to only get one backing field, which is the one in the `Derived` class. Why is that so? The `Derived` class can still access `base.Value`, have logic for it, etc, and yet its value seems to be missing from the class. Is there a way to access it through reflection? What is the reason that this value does not show up when reflecting through the `Derived` type? (Note: I realize I can reflect through `Base` and get the value, but I am asking why is that value not showing up when we reflect through `Derived` even though its clearly there and can be manipulated).

**EDIT:** If instead both `Value` members were declared as fields instead of properties, the behavior is "normal" and reflection will get both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get the same results (or I misunderstand what you're saying).

If I write this code (using your `Base` and `Derived` classes):

```
var properties = typeof(Derived).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
    Console.WriteLine("Property Name: {0}, Type: {1}", propertyInfo.Name, propertyInfo.PropertyType.FullName);
```

I get this output:

```
Property Name: TestValue, Type: System.String
Property Name: TestValue, Type: System.Int32
```

So I'm seeing both properties using reflection, not just one.

However, when reflecting the fields, I only get the ones in the derived class.

The documentation for [`Type.GetFields()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/6ztex2dc.aspx) says:

> Only protected and internal fields on base classes are returned; private fields on base classes are not returned.

Which matches my observations.

Comment: So I have to loop over the hierarchy of the `Derived` class if I want to obtain the private backing field in `Base`?

Comment: @NickolayRatchev According to the documentation for `Type.GetFields()`, it seems so. Also see this answer, which might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201859/why-doesnt-type-getfields-return-backing-fields-in-a-base-class